# A Space Gravitational Bus Route - is there such a thing?

Tags: mars, spacecraft, gravity

Don't know if this is already been thought of, if it has it would be cool to know the name?

Fundamental problem in how the public sees space transport, the problem is we see it as firing a rocking from object a to go object b however a more elegant solution would be to have a constant motion which gradually speeds up overtime.

The reason we are not building long distant space craft is because we believe that if we build it now, tomorrow the new space craft will be faster and will overtake it......

I'm defining a mission to mars as being long distant I also defining that by tomorrow I mean before the mission has been completed....

It takes around 150-300 days to get to mars depending on the launch, 50 days give or take thats not bad.

Okay so lets get to the point.... we fire a rocket this rocket takes 150 days to get to mars its unmanned we leave it to continuously slingshot from mars to earth and back again.

This provides a continuous supply between Earth and Mars. It would be cool to know the name of this if it exists?

Comment: How does that provide a continuous supply ?

Comment: How do you get from Earth to your rocket? i.e. catch the bus.

Comment: See [Mars cycler](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_cycler)

Comment: OK, so how fast is the Mars (or Aldrin) cycler going at closest approach to Mars and at closest approach to Earth? That's the delta-V you'd need to bring with you to "get on and off" the bus.

Comment: @antzi This is a continuous supply because it provides a stream of things to and from Earth and Mars.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The "Please discuss..." part of my question was thrown in... There is obviously a question here! and obviously an answer however I wanted people to get the impression that it was an open question to everyone.... That all ideas are welcome... :)

Comment: Good point, I did ramble I will shorten it down... Thank you :)

Comment: Your edit is an improvement, Jake. I think it this now doesn't need closing. Welcome to Space Exploration.

Comment: You may be interested in [In space, do “shipping lanes” make sense?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/16/29) on [worldbuilding.se]. I haven't re-reviewed the answers, but as I recall, some of them do touch on this exact concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Mars cycler to provide continuous supply between Earth and Mars, we have to load it at each flyby.

To load it with cargo, we have to perform a rendezvous, that is: match its velocity/timing. So to dock with the cycler, you have to spend the same energy as what would be required to go to/from Mars in the first place!

Of course, the cycler can help your logistics. It can provide deep space communication, power facility, life support, ...

This is a very interesting concept for manned flight, but as long as we just send robots/satellites to Mars, the cycler is of very limited interest.

Comment: The energy needed is reduced because the mass of the rendezvous rocket is lower because the systems you mention are on the cycler. The more trips the cycler does, the more there is a net savings there. The rendezvous on the Mars end, on the other hand, means the cycler doesn't need to haul equipment for entry, descent and landing, so that makes the cycler lighter.

Comment: @kimholder for dead cargo, this sound quite minimal ...

Comment: It would certainly have more of an effect if the cycler had people on it. Shielding mass for cosmic radiation and solar storms could be a lot and make a big difference. At any rate, minor weight savings make a significant difference because of the way fuel needs climb exponentially.

Comment: @kimholder so does the launch timing constraints :D
And more systems <=> more risks of failure.